# JS loop does not works (variable undefined but single selection works)

Tags: javascript

I'm completely stumped.. 
I uploaded a csv file to my database and now my application should "play" with it..

After my select, I want to split this file into his elements. This is my code:

```
var file = result[0].FILE;
var entries;
var lines = {
    line: []
};
var i;
var allLines = file.split(/[\r\n]+/g);

for(i = 0; i <= allLines.length; i++) {
    entries = allLines[i].split(';');
    lines.line.push({
        DATEVALUE: entries[0],
        VALUE: entries[1]
    });
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> allLines[i]is not defined

Well... `allLines` has a length of 182 elements and if I use something like `allLines[0]`or `allLines[1]` instead of `allLines[I]` everything is okay. **But why does the loop does not works**?

My select looks like (**Output with JSON.stringify()**):

> [
>       "2014-01-01 00:00:00;309",
>       "2014-01-02 00:15:00;198",
>       "2014-01-03 00:30:00;274",
>       "2014-01-04 00:45:00;140",
>       "2014-01-05 01:00:00;167",
>       "2014-01-06 01:15:00;276",
>       "2014-01-07 01:30:00;283",
>       "2014-01-08 01:45:00;304", ... ]

Comment: Walk through your programmer with a debugger to track down the error. That's what all the cool boys and girls do. Or add some console.log statements. Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are 0-indexed (their subscripts start from 0). So if an array contain `N` elements and the first element is `0` then the last element will be `N - 1` not `N`. So `array[array.length]` is `undefined`. Change the `for` loop from this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= allLines.length; i++) {
    // ...
```

to this:

```
for(i = 0; i < allLines.length; i++) {
    // ...
```

**MATH**:

```
TheNumberOfItems = LastItemIndex - FirstItemIndex + 1;
```

so:

```
array.length = x - 0 + 1; // where x is the index of the last item
```

then:

```
x = array.length - 1;
```

so the last element of the array is `array.length - 1` not `array.length`. So if the condition for the loop was `i <= array.length` then at some point `array[array.length]` will be evaluated (to `undefined`).